# Mapping jj to Escape doesn‘t work over SSH connection

Tags: key-bindings, escape

When I connect to a remote server via iterm2 and SSH and use vim on this server remapping to the Escape key doesn't work. Other key mappings in the `.vimrc` work as expected but `inoremap jj <Esc>` won‘t leave the insert mode but writes `jj` inside the text no matter how fast I type.

I tried an SSH connection with macOS's Terminal.app with the same result. Is this related to the SSH? How can I solve the problem?

*Update:*

`:set to? tm?`

returns

```
timeout
timeoutlen=1000
```

*Update 2:*

It seems that all normal and visual mode mappings work but insert mode mappings fail. I also tried

`inoremap > <TAB>`

without success.

`:verbose set paste?`

returns

```
    paste
         Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: Might be related to `timeout` and similar settings

Comment: But how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does `:set to? tm?` tell you? Does it say `notimeout`? Please update the question with the output of this command.

Comment: Try disabling the timeout, with `:set noto` and see if that helps? Or increase the timeout length to, say, 5 seconds, with `:set tm=5000`? It's odd that it would take longer than 1s to receive to `j`s over SSH... But anyways, check those commands to see if they help.

Comment: Have you double checked that the mapping actually exists? Does anything change if you set up the mapping manually from inside the Vim session, rather than from your vimrc?

Comment: @filbranden @Rich I tried but nothing worked. As fast as I type or as slow as I type on any of these setting I see the two `j` appear one after another in the text. Setting the mapping from inside Vim doesn't work either.

Comment: You say that other mappings work: are these insert mode mappings, or normal mode? If you don’t have any other insert mode mappings, can you try creating one? What is the output of `:verbose set paste?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `paste` set, insert mode mappings are disabled (among other things). `paste` is only meant to be set during, well, a paste. Otherwise, leave it off.

Comment: Solved! Thanks, `set nopaste` was the key.